# UIAlertView delegate method crashing

Tags: iphone, delegates, uialertview, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my iPhone app, I have a `NSObject`A class and a `UIViewController` B class. I want to call a instance method in B class from A. I used the following code.

```
Bclass *vc = [[Bclass alloc]init];
[vc hideAlert:NSString];
[vc release];
```

and in B class:

```
- (void)hideAlert:(NSString*)message{
    UIAlertView *shareAlrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [shareAlrt show];
    [shareAlrt release];
}
```

and the method called and show a AlertView. When click on the Ok button, I want to navigate to class Cclass.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        Cclass *vc = [[Cclass alloc]initWithNibName:@"Cclass" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
        [vc release];
    }
}
```

But when I click on the Ok button, the app crashes. Whats happening here? I have added `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in the B class.h file, but still the same error. Please help

I am getting the error code `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81baa80'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the method

```
- (void)hideAlert:(NSString*)message{
    UIAlertView *shareAlrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [shareAlrt show];
    [shareAlrt release];
}
```

Comment: hi, i am still having the issue. When I call the delegate method from any other AlertViews, it is working fine. But, when i click the Ok button on the alert view that came from above method is not working.

Comment: In delegate method condition check the UIAlertView name & perform the action accordingly. Like `if(alertview == your_alertview_name)` then perfrom some action & so on

Comment: @Mithun: what problem you are facing when you click the Ok button on the alert view ?

Comment: i am calling - (void)hideAlert:(NSString*)message from A class, and showing alert view. When click on the Ok button, I want to navigate to another view. I am getting the alert view, but when click on the OK button, getting the error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81baa80'.

Comment: but I have created another alert view in B class on a UIButton action, which is in the B class itself, and when i clicked on the OK button, it is working fine. So the issue is only with the alert view from the above method.

Comment: there is no code for alert in class A. I am simply calling a method in class B and that method contains the alert view.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder i tried that too. But its crashing before it reaching the delegate method.

Comment: @Mithun: I am not getting you properly...But my first guess is that `[vc release];` causes crash. Because you are creating obj of class B and very next line you are releasing it so...

Comment: hey guys, fixed the issue. I used NSNotification center for invoking the method. Now it works fine. Anyway thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered by presuming that u have no other button except cancel button titled as "OK". Assumption is made by seeing your displayed code.

You have used Cancel button on which u cant handle delegate to perform any action.

If you look at the documentation of **UIAlertViewDelegate class reference**

> Optionally, you can implement the alertViewCancel: method to take the
>   appropriate action when the system cancels your alert view. If the
>   delegate does not implement this method, the default behavior is to
>   simulate the user clicking the cancel button and closing the view.

Comment: I have added - (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView into the code, but when I clicked on the button, this method is not getting called.

Comment: So u mean, What I said that u have used 'cancel button' only titled as "OK". right?

Comment: yes, you are right. It is cancel button and its name is "OK".

Comment: I dont know why your `- (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView Cancel` is not getting called. Actually it should get called. but..hmmm. BTW ***Maulik's*** approach can be adopted time being to get rid of problem & proceed further to achieve your goal

Comment: Who the hell has down-voted the answer? I really feel pity on him. At least he could have commented reason behind down-voting   X-(